# Media queries for Iphone Ipad

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad, media

I want to hide two div's and show one div when on ipad or iphone.
while working with media queries i been able to hide two div's but the one i want to show is not showing on ipad or iphone the code i am using.

```
<link media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="/cs_common/css/ipad/ipad-landscape.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<link media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation:portrait)"  href="/cs_common/css/ipad/ipad-portrait.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link media="all and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/cs_common/css/ipad/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<style>
  .newrugtoolsel 
 {

     visibility:hidden;

  }

  .newrugsearch
  {
      visibility:hidden;
  }
  .bottom
  {
      display:block;



  }

</style>


<html>
<div  class="bottom"  style=" width:100%; height:80px; background-color:blue; position: fixed; left:0px; bottom:0px; display:none;"> This is the div i want to show on ipad or iphone and hide on desktop </div>
</html
```

the div i want to show is .bottom

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the style sheets after you style for your whole site or the  tags will override what you media stylesheets say.

```
<style>
  .newrugtoolsel 
 {

     visibility:hidden;

  }

  .newrugsearch
  {
      visibility:hidden;
  }
  .bottom
  {
      display:block;



  }

</style>

    <link media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="/cs_common/css/ipad/ipad-landscape.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<link media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 800px) and (orientation:portrait)"  href="/cs_common/css/ipad/ipad-portrait.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link media="all and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="/cs_common/css/ipad/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would put the css in the stylesheet. Remove it from your html page, and put it all in the different stylesheets.

Should work with the way you are thinking, but specify it in every stylesheet in stead of in your html.

Comment: you should not have style in your html, but rather class.
The .bottom, is to set class, and style as @Ben said, will override the css ;)